# DataTables bindings with KnockoutJS and Knockout-mapper.js not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I a following tutorial from [here](https://abrudtkuhl.github.io/Simple-Knockout-Js-Paging-Datatables/) on how to bind DataTables with KnockoutJS and Knockout mapper. From what i can see i only need to give my object and apply binding to table but when i do it i don't get anything (no errors and no display data). What am i missing?

Controller JSON data:

```
public virtual JsonResult GetRecordsJsonResult()
    {
        var userBusinessLogic = InterfaceResolver.ResolveWithTransaction<IUserBusinessLogic>();
        var records = userBusinessLogic.GetAll().Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            x.FirstName,
            x.LastName,
            x.Email
        }).OrderBy(i => i.Id);

        var data = Json(new
        {
            max = records.Count(),
            items = records
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return data;
    }
```

JSON data example that i get
[image: JSON data example]

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        function viewModel(data) {
            console.log("viewModel");
            var self = this;
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
            console.log(self);
            console.log("data");
            console.log(data);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetRecordsJsonResult")", success: function (data) {
                ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(data));
                $("#items").DataTable({ responsive: true });
            }
        });
    });

 </script>

<table id="items" class="display table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.Id"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.FirstName"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.LastName"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.Emaiol"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Console log from browser:
[image: No errors]

I think there might be an error in how i get my items from controller since everything is working fine when i follow tutorial. Any ideas? Thank you for your time.

Comment: does it show table without the line `$("#items").DataTable({ responsive: true });`? Also use `<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">`

Comment: Thank you, i was missing <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">

Answer (score 0):

yes there are many things wrong with the above example... This is the easiest solution for getting knockout to play nicely with datatables...

This solution uses a custom binding that I created that depends on a knockout fork.  If you like this solution please leave a comment on the pull request to get it merged intp knockout 3.4, Thanks.

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/4tLabu56/)

[knockout pull request](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1856)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DataTablesForEach = {

        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
             var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
                if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                }
            });
            return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            key = "DataTablesForEach_Initialized";

            var newValue = function () {
                return {
                    data: value.data || value,
                    beforeRenderAll: function (el, index, data) {

                        if (ko.utils.domData.get(element, key)) {
                            $(element).closest('table').DataTable().clear();
                            $(element).closest('table').DataTable().destroy();
                        }
                    },
                    afterRenderAll: function (el, index, data) {
                        $(element).closest('table').DataTable(value.options);
                    }

                };
            };

            ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValue, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

            //if we have not previously marked this as initialized and there is currently items in the array, then cache on the element that it has been initialized
            if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (value.data || value.length)) {
                ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
            }

            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
```